# Hide GCC warning "set but not used"?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings, hide

I want to do a function to get a pointer on a struct.
I done this :

```
void *getTokenList() {
    static t_token *list;

    return &list;
}
```

At compilation, I have this warning :
**`warning: variable ‘list’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`**

Is it possible to disable this warning for this function (only this one), or put an GCC attribute on this variable to hide this warning?

I had put `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"` in top of my file but I want to hide this warning ONLY for this variable in this function.

Thanks,
Jean

Comment: which version of gcc is giving you that? Mine (gcc 4.5.2) doesn't. This is definitively bogus, if you really return an address of that variable to the caller.

Comment: '''I had put `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"` in top of my file''', that's a great trick. It worked perfectly for me as the unused variables were in a file I take from an external developer and I wanted to add minimal changes to it ...

Comment: That warning doesn't make any sense, because in your example, `list` is not set. You are using a pointer to `list` without setting `list`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this to shut it off:

```
(void)list;
```

Alternatively and less portably you can use [`__attribute__((unused))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes).

Comment: +1 Although __attribute__((unused)) is a lot clearer, it's definitively not portable!

Answer (score 2):

`static t_token *__attribute__((unused)) list;`

Answer (score 1):

This warning was a bug in **gcc**. The warning, introduced in version 4.6, can easy be disabled as explained in other answers, but it should be noted that [current versions of **gcc**](https://godbolt.org/z/6GbhMr77x) do not produce the warning.

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming C23 standard will provide *attributes* as a standardized way to consider such cases (very similar to attributes in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)).

With this you can write

```
[[maybe_unused]] static t_token *list;
```

Although not yet standardized, the functionality is already available from gcc 10.1, even with pre C23 code, see [this example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Pqhzn8GcM).

Further resources:

- [Working Draft N2596](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf), "6.7.11.3 The maybe_unused attribute"
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/attributes